# Why do I get different string when recreating string through charlists

Tags: elixir

```
iex(1)> 'hełło'         
[104, 101, 322, 322, 111]
iex(2)>  <<104, 101, 322, 322, 111>>
"heBBo"
```

Shouldn't `<<104, 101, 322, 322, 111>>` return "hełło" as it uses the same codepoints?

Answer (score 4):

I understand now, when the values go beyong 255, bitstring needs to be told how to encode the value. The following prints string correctly.

```
 <<104, 101, 322::utf8, 322::utf8, 111>> #=> "hełło"
```

Edit1: to add more details on why I got "heBBo", it's important to understand how the truncation of values work. A byte can store a maximum value of 256. If a value, such as 322, is given, what gets stored is actually 322-256 i.e.,66 which is the codepoint of 'B'.

So my entry of `<<104, 101, 322, 322, 111>>` got truncated to <<104, 101, 66, 66, 111>>, resulting in "heBBo".